# Custom project import wizard in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, custom-action

Is it possible to have some kind of automagic configuration or custom code execution with Eclipse, so that importing a new Java source project from svn/git/xyz would run something (automatically asking for permissions, with behavior similar to Windows autorun) comparable to ./configure or like a new program installation wizard on Windows (asking for local paths or detecting and updating necessary code variables for Unix integration)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use Maven to do this, maven lets you generate Eclipse project files, you can probably take any custom action you want after this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a small Eclipse plugin to get that kind of behaviour:

http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/